# Forward WIFI traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn

I am trying to set up my raspberry pi as a WIFI access point which itself connects to a VPN through PPTP.

Here is what I have done:

1. Managed to make my raspberry pi an WIFI access point. I am able to see it and connect to it. I followed that [tutorial](http://qcktech.blogspot.dk/2012/08/raspberry-pi-as-router.html).
2. Managed to route all the traffic through PPTP VPN using this [tutorial](https://devtidbits.com/2013/02/19/using-a-point-to-point-tunnelling-protocol-virtual-private-network-pptp-vpn-client-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

**Problems ?**

As I mentioned above, both 1 and 2 were successfully implemented, the problem is how can I make them work together ...

So whenever I activate my PPTP configuration with `sudo pon my_fancy_conf updetach` all the raspbbery-pi traffic gets through the VPN (tested with 
`traceroute google.com` command) **BUT** at that time all the connected devices to the WIFI access point are hanging up and they cant reach the internet via the raspberry pi anymore.  Turning off the `PPTP` with `sudo poff -a`, gets the internet access back to devices but not through a VPN....

In other words the situation is like:

If I turn on the PPTP VPN on my `PI` the WIFI access points stop working, while internet is still accessible from the `PI` via the VPN.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

Running `route -n` command gives me:

[image]

Running `ifconfig` on one of the wireless clients

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
        options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether 20:c9:d0:7b:8e:53 
        inet6 fe80::413:aece:8fc5:f28f%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
        inet 192.168.42.10 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.42.255
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
        options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
        ether 32:00:15:e7:43:40 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
        options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
        ether 32:00:15:e7:43:41 
        media: autoselect <full-duplex>
        status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
       ether 32:00:15:e7:43:40 
        Configuration:
                id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
                maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
                root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
                ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
        member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
                ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
        member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
                ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: <unknown type>
        status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
        ether 02:c9:d0:7b:8e:53 
        media: autoselect
        status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
        ether 1a:0b:74:02:6c:de 
        inet6 fe80::180b:74ff:fe02:6cde%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
        media: autoselect
        status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
        inet6 fe80::3f29:3e26:c979:8830%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
        inet6 fe80::758c:e052:d6f7:e76a%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
        nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

Comment: Who is supplying the ip addresses to the wireless clients? What is the gateway address for the clients? Possibly your local router?

Comment: I have updated the question @LotPings

Comment: If the route output is from the Pi that doesn't answer my questions. What output do get from an ifconfig/ipconfig from the wireless clients?

Comment: Alright ! Update the question again.

Comment: Sorry I'm more common in the windows world, on Linux clients the route -n is more helpful to show the gateway.